# How to wait for a response

Tags: python, get, python-requests, wait

So I'm trying to get some data from a search engine. This search engine returns some results and then, after for example 2 seconds, it changes it's html and show some approximate results.

I want to get these approximate results but that's the problem. I use `requests.get` which gets first response and does not wait those for example 2 seconds. So I'm curious if it is possible.

I don't want to use a Selenium since it has to be as lite as possible because it will be a part of a web page.

So my question is: Is it possible to make `requests.get` wait for another data?

Comment: Could you provide the website? Specific URL

Comment: Have you inspected what the HTTP request that happens in the page? Are you sure that the second data comes through the same request?

Answer (score 1):

No, since requests is just an HTTP client.

It looks like the page is being modified by JS after finishing other request. You should figure out, what request changes the page and use it (by network inspector in Chrome, for example).